# Other ways of converting part of array to subarray in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

When parsing CSV file I need to combine fields of a row into an array starting from 4th field (3rd array element). I want to manipulate each row as in example below:
Original array:

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Changed array:

```
array2 = [1,2,3,[4,5]]
```

My code is here:

```
array1[0..2].push(array1[3..array1.length])

=> [1, 2, 3, [4, 5]]
```

My question is: Is there a better/cleaner/simpler way to convert part of an array into subarray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is! You can do this
`a = a[0..2] + [a[3..-1]]`. In ruby `+` can be used to concatenate arrays. Additionally, `n..-1` gives you elements `n` to the end of the array. As a caveat, `+` is slower and more expensive than `concat` so if you were to do `a[0..2].concat([a[3..-1])` it will be cheaper and faster.

Comment: Actually, I just realized I need the resulting array to be like this; `["1", "2", "3", [4, 5]]` - convert String to Integer for subarray. Utilizing your suggestion my code looks like this:

Comment: `a = ["1","2","3","4","5"]` `a = a[0..2].concat([a[3..-1].map(&:to_i)])` can this be improved? Sorry, I do's seem to be able to edit this comment

Comment: What does "cheaper" in "cheaper and faster" mean? You could also write `a[0..2] << a[3..-1]`.

Comment: @Cary Awesome profile read, by the way ;) would you comment on my comment? is there a better way to convert subarray to Integers? `a = ["1","2","3","4","5"] a = a[0..2].concat([a[3..-1].map(&:to_i)])` there seem to always be another way in Ruby.

Comment: clonecq, I would be inclined to do the converstion first: `aa = a.map(&:to) #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; aa[0..2] << aa[3..-1] #=>  [1, 2, 3, [4, 5]]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland "cheaper" means less memory intense. `a + b` creates a new array so three arrays have memory allocated whereas `a.concat(b)` concatenates `b` to `a` so only two arrays have memory allocated. Faster means that it runs more quickly.